# Different type object passing

Tags: java, android

I am beginner of android and java.I did no understand when object pass.Object pass of course need implement Serializable.

0.When do use Serializable? what is it?

1.what is Object and Bundle Class.

2.When use Object and Bundle for passing Object

3.Do support Object and Bundle object all data type object?

please help me.Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should start with an elementary Java tutorial.

Comment: yah bro.But please tell me this question.I am searching but i can not understand.

Comment: What is `Bundle class` indeed? It's not in the JDK. What do you mean by 'object pass?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really vague what you are asking but serializable objects can be transformed into a stream of bits that can be deserialized back into the object.  You can use this to clone objects, put them in a stream, or send them over a network.

Comment: thanks bro..i ask mainly 1.what is Object and Bundle Class.

2.When use Object and Bundle for passing Object

3.Do support Object and Bundle object all data type object?

Comment: @user3515725 And you've been asked what you mean by all that, and you haven't answered. Instead you're just repeating yourself, both here and in your additional question. Don't do that.